# How can I prove that the determinant of the matrix is $0$ only when $a=b=c=d=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, laplace-expansion

How can I prove that the determinant of the matrix is $0$ only when $a=b=c=d=0$? I tried with the Laplace Method of Expansion but I cannot solve the final equation.

\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c & \ d \\
        b & -a & d & \ -c \\
        c & -d & -a & \ b \\
        d & c & -b & \ -a \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your final equation?

Comment: I came to this equation: a^4 -(a*d)^2 -b*d*a*(-c)-b*d*(-a)*c-b^2*c^2+c^4 = 0

Comment: Alternatively, the determinant is just the signed volume of the parallepiped spanned by the columns. In this case, the four columns (regarded as vectors in $\mathbb R^4$) have the same length and are pairwise orthogonal, so that the parallelepiped they span is a hypercube with side length $s := \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$ and hence (hyper)volume $s^4 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2$, which is zero iff $a = b = c = d = 0$.